# InfogainLoss layer

Tags: numpy, neural-network, protocol-buffers, deep-learning, caffe

I wish to use a loss layer of type [`InfogainLoss`](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/doxygen/classcaffe_1_1InfogainLossLayer.html#details) in my model. But I am having difficulties defining it properly.

1. Is there any tutorial/example on the usage of `INFOGAIN_LOSS` layer?
2. Should the input to this layer, the class probabilities, be the output of a `SOFTMAX` layer, or is it enough to input the "top" of a fully connected layer?

`INFOGAIN_LOSS` requires three inputs: class probabilities, labels and the matrix `H`.
The matrix `H` can be provided either as a layer parameters `infogain_loss_param { source: "fiename" }`.
Suppose I have a python script that computes `H` as a `numpy.array` of shape `(L,L)` with `dtype='f4'` (where `L` is the number of labels in my model).

3. How can I convert my `numpy.array` into a `binproto` file that can be provided as a `infogain_loss_param { source }` to the model?
4. Suppose I want `H` to be provided as the third input (bottom) to the loss layer (rather than as a model parameter). How can I do this?
   Do I define a new data layer which "top" is `H`? If so, wouldn't the data of this layer be incremented every training iteration like the training data is incremented?
   How can I define multiple unrelated input "data" layers, and how does caffe know to read from the training/testing "data" layer batch after batch, while from the `H` "data" layer it knows to read only once for all the training process?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*1. Is there any tutorial/example on the usage of **InfogainLoss** layer?*:
A nice example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30486033/tackling-class-imbalance-scaling-contribution-to-loss-and-sgd?lq=1): using **InfogainLoss** to tackle class imbalance.

---

*2. Should the input to this layer, the class probabilities, be the output of a **Softmax** layer?*
Historically, the answer used to be *YES* according to [Yair's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30037614/1714410). The old implementation of `"InfogainLoss"` needed to be the output of `"Softmax"` layer or any other layer that makes sure the input values are in range [0..1].

The [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1714410/shai) noticed that using `"InfogainLoss"` on top of `"Softmax"` layer can lead to numerical instability. [His pull request](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/3855), combining these two layers into a single one (much like `"SoftmaxWithLoss"` layer), was accepted and merged into the official Caffe repositories on 14/04/2017. The mathematics of this combined layer are given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34917052/1714410).

The upgraded layer "look and feel" is exactly like the old one, apart from the fact that **one no longer needs to explicitly pass the input through a `"Softmax"` layer.**

---

*3. How can I convert an numpy.array into a binproto file*:

In python

```
H = np.eye( L, dtype = 'f4' ) 
import caffe
blob = caffe.io.array_to_blobproto( H.reshape( (1,1,L,L) ) )
with open( 'infogainH.binaryproto', 'wb' ) as f :
    f.write( blob.SerializeToString() )
```

Now you can add to the model prototext the `INFOGAIN_LOSS` layer with `H` as a parameter:

```
layer {
  bottom: "topOfPrevLayer"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "infoGainLoss"
  name: "infoGainLoss"
  type: "InfogainLoss"
  infogain_loss_param {
    source: "infogainH.binaryproto"
  }
}
```

---

*4. How to load `H` as part of a DATA layer*

Quoting [Evan Shelhamer's post](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/1640):

> There's no way at present to make data layers load input at different rates. Every forward pass all data layers will advance. However, the constant H input could be done by making an input lmdb / leveldb / hdf5 file that is only H since the data layer will loop and keep loading the same H. This obviously wastes disk IO.

Comment: This solves parts 3 and 4 completely, and is a perfect solution for anyone who wants to re-weight (or balance) the per-class losses in Caffe, using InfoGain layer and the prototxt definition of H

Answer (score 2):

The layer is summing up

```
-log(p_i)
```

and so the p_i's need to be in (0, 1] to make sense as a loss function (otherwise higher confidence scores will produce a higher loss). See the curve below for the values of log(p).

[image]

I don't think they have to sum up to 1, but passing them through a Softmax layer will achieve both properties.

Comment: it's not exactly this sum, there are also weights

Comment: Yes, there are the weights but they are not the factor that constrains the value of p_i. log(p) < 0 for 0<x<1 so -log(p) is positive, and the loss increases as p becomes smaller (which is what you need). if p > 1 log(p) > 0 and so -log(p) will increase as p becomes smaller. This is the opposite of what the loss function should do. That is why p needs to be in (0, 1]. log(0) = -infinity so care should be taken not to have p=0, but that is already implemented in the layer itself.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, your answer to question number 2 is: the input to `info_gain` layer should be the "top" of a `softmax` layer.

Comment: Yes. That would be a good way to be sure the values are in the correct range.

Answer (score 1):

Since I had to search through many websites to puzzle the complete
code, I thought I share my implementation:

Python layer for computing the H-matrix with weights for each class:

```
import numpy as np
import caffe


class ComputeH(caffe.Layer):
    def __init__(self, p_object, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ComputeH, self).__init__(p_object, *args, **kwargs)
        self.n_classes = -1

    def setup(self, bottom, top):
        if len(bottom) != 1:
            raise Exception("Need (only) one input to compute H matrix.")

        params = eval(self.param_str)
        if 'n_classes' in params:
            self.n_classes = int(params['n_classes'])
        else:
            raise Exception('The number of classes (n_classes) must be specified.')

    def reshape(self, bottom, top):
        top[0].reshape(1, 1, self.n_classes, self.n_classes)

    def forward(self, bottom, top):
        classes, cls_num = np.unique(bottom[0].data, return_counts=True)

        if np.size(classes) != self.n_classes or self.n_classes == -1:
            raise Exception("Invalid number of classes")

        cls_num = cls_num.astype(float)

        cls_num = cls_num.max() / cls_num
        weights = cls_num / np.sum(cls_num)

        top[0].data[...] = np.diag(weights)

    def backward(self, top, propagate_down, bottom):
        pass
```

and the relevant part from the train_val.prototxt:

```
layer {
    name: "computeH"
    bottom: "label"
    top: "H"
    type: "Python"
    python_param {
        module: "digits_python_layers"
        layer: "ComputeH"
        param_str: '{"n_classes": 7}'
    }
    exclude { stage: "deploy" }
}
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "InfogainLoss"
  bottom: "score"
  bottom: "label"
  bottom: "H"
  top: "loss"
  infogain_loss_param {
    axis: 1  # compute loss and probability along axis
  }
  loss_param {
      normalization: 0
  }
  exclude {
    stage: "deploy"
  }
}
```

Comment: I have 2 classes and my batch size for TRAIN/TEST is 16 and what if while sampling all my labels are same in that batch (i.e. from the majority class). This makes `np.unique(bottom[0].data, return_counts=True)` return `(array([1.], dtype=float32), array([16]))` which means my `num_classes` get assigned `1` instead of `2`.

Comment: If you know the number of classes in advance, you can specify it as a constant.