# InfoGainLoss leads to accuracy and loss of 0

Tags: neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I'm trying to train a Net for semantic segmentation with class imbalance. To account for this, i tried to implement the InfoGainLoss layer and specified the infogain_matrix as was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42344936/how-to-solve-this-issue-in-python-creating-weights-for-infogain-loss-layer), where I instead used 1- frequency(class) for each diagonal element.
When training the [net](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0_PYuQUr6uZUTdnNFZ1bE1EQTQ) however, both accuracy and loss immediately converge to 0, even with low base_lr, and the net labels everything as class 0 ("unknown"). My question now is whether the infogain_matrix should be specified as in the post I linked and if so what other reasons could be for this unusual behaviour of the net ( I expected either loss 0 accuracy 1 or loss INF accuracy 0).

Edit:
So when i run the Net with the SoftMaxWithLoss layer instead of InfoGainLoss, it immediately starts to classify everything as the most representative class (class1 with 90%), and doesn't change anymore. My guess now is that i configured the lmdb for the infogain_matrix incorrectly. Does anybody know if one has to specify the dtype of the lmdb for the caffe data layer (images and infogain_matrix are stored as float32), though [caffe documentation for the layer](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/layers/data.html) does not say so? Or moreover, what dtypes the caffe data layer expects from the lmdb?
lmdbs were generated using the code taken/modified from [here](http://deepdish.io/2015/04/28/creating-lmdb-in-python/), but for the images mean subtraction was performed priorily. I tested lmdb readout in python, and here i had to specify the dtype, as otherwise reshape into the original matrix dimensions throwed errors.

Edit2:
So the mistake indeed was in the lmdb definition, as for dtype=float, data needs to be appended to datum.float_data instead of datum.data, see [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/caffe-users/lmdb$20dtype%7Csort:relevance/caffe-users/A8N4l4Ippbo/OxjFQQHYBwAJ). Now everything looks okay and the accuracies and losses are no locker whacky :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake was in the lmdb definition, as for dtype=float, the data needs to be appended to datum.float_data instead of datum.data (which needs to be left empty so that caffe automatically scans datum.float_data); [SOURCE](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/caffe-users/lmdb$20dtype%7Csort:relevance/caffe-users/A8N4l4Ippbo/OxjFQQHYBwAJ)

So the code from [here](http://deepdish.io/2015/04/28/creating-lmdb-in-python/) for generating lmdb dataset with python could be modified as follows:

```
with env.begin(write=True) as txn:
    # txn is a Transaction object
    for i in range(N):
        datum = caffe.proto.caffe_pb2.Datum()
        datum.channels = X.shape[1]
        datum.height = X.shape[2]
        datum.width = X.shape[3]
        datum.float_data.extend(X[i].astype(float).flat)
        datum.label = int(y[i])
        str_id = '{:08}'.format(i)
        # The encode is only essential in Python 3
        txn.put(str_id.encode('ascii'), datum.SerializeToString())
```

The thing is, caffe doesn't throw errors if you wrongly append float data to datum.data instead of datum.float_data, but will result in whacky behaviour like accuracy and loss both going to 0 (as the infogain_mat H may be 0 for certain classes due to dtype mismatch)