# What Loss layer can be used for median frequency balancing? How?

Tags: caffe, pycaffe, matcaffe

I have written a python script which calculates the **median frequency balancing** weights for each class during the pixel-wise segmentation. Then, I added a `Python Layer` to the `caffe` model definition, which sends the weights to the loss function. Based on [this link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2049), user mentions that `SoftmaxWithLoss` layer in caffe correspond to TensorFlow `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`. 
My question is how can I send the weights to **SoftmaxWithLoss** layer? 
What other Loss layers can be used with `median frequency balancing`? I used `InfoGainLoss`, but it does not converge. Your help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to weight the `"SoftmaxLoss"` (i.e., cross entropy loss) according to classes then [`"InfogainLoss"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30497907/1714410) is what you need.
Note that infogain layer was upgraded in caffe a few months ago: it now integrates `"Softmax"` into the loss computation for robust gradient estimation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I applied `InfoGainLoss`, however, it is over-segmenting. I do not know what is the reason. My other question is that "`Softmax`" does not have any parameter that I can feed the weights by using that, could I to explain more? Thanks