# error classification (entirely 1st class) with InfoGainLoss layer caffe

Tags: caffe

according to [InfogainLoss layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27632440/infogainloss-layer)
I have replace SoftMaxWithLoss -> InfoGainLoss from branch https://github.com/shaibagon/caffe/tree/upgrade_infogain (which robustly combines softmax layer and infogain loss layer).

Now all predictions are 1st class only.

Any     suppositions?

additional info
solver, net, H and log my sover, net, generator H matrix, and log.

https://drive.google.com/a/smedx.com/file/d/0B4lunYl8YWUOQ3U3NzN6Tll5NEE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I cannot access the gdrive link you posted. can you post the information somewhere more accessible?

Comment: Hi Alkor, it seems you have (perhaps accidentally) created two accounts; https://stackoverflow.com/users/5982852/alkor and http://stackoverflow.com/users/5982868/alkor. If you wish to merge them, please follow the steps at http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setting `base_lr: 0.001` instead of 0.01 has solve the problem.