# A special loss function in caffe

Tags: caffe, loss

I have a kind of euclidean loss function which is:

```
\sum_{i,j} c_i*max{0,y_{ji}-k_{ji}} + p_i*max{0,k_{ji}-y_{ji}}
```

which `y_{ji}` are the output of caffe and `k_{ji}` are the real output value, `i` is the index of the items and `j` is index of samples.

The issue is about getting the values of parameters `c_i` and `p_i`.

When I have `c_i = c_q for all i \neq q`, and similarly for `p_i`, I simply get the values of them as parameters of the loss layer (I added two new parameters in the caffe.proto). However, the problems is that now I have around 300 items so that it is not reasonable to get them as loss layer parameters. 
I tried to get their values in the loss layer, I mean I tried to add another `bottom layer` for loss layer, but it gave an error. 
I am stuck here!

Please guide me how I can solve this issue.

Thanks in advance,
Afshin

Comment: look at `"InfogainLoss"` layer where you have an additional matrix of parameters. See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27632440/1714410) for example.

Comment: @Shai Thanks for the comment. I looked at the layer, but it can be used with a output of range [0,1], which is not my case here. I have a continues output. One approach could be scaling the output, but in this way I will lose accuracy.

Comment: I was not expecting you to use `"infogainLoss"`, but rather see how getting the weights is implemented there: either as an additional `"bottom"`, or as a binaryproto file with the weights written in it.

Comment: @Shai
I see, I found this [link](https://github.com/gustavla/caffe-weighted-samples/blob/master/src/caffe/layers/softmax_loss_layer.cpp), I think it can help. But, compared to tensorflow it requires a lot of work to do a simple change.  :|

Comment: you can always write your loss layer as a `"Python"` layer...