# Use mean file in hdf5 in caffe

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I'm preparing to train in Caffe using data in a hdf5 file. This file also contains the per-pixel mean data/image of the training set. In the file `'train_val.prototxt'` for the input data layer in the section `'transform_params'` it is possible to use a `mean_file` to normalize the data, usually in binaryproto format, for example for the [ImageNet Caffe tutorial example](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/imagenet.html):

```
transform_param {
  mirror: true
  crop_size: 227
  mean_file: "data/ilsvrc12/imagenet_mean.binaryproto"
}
```

For per-channel normalization one can instead use [mean_value](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/train_val.prototxt) instead of mean_file.

But is there any way to use mean image data directly from my database (here hdf5) file?

I have extracted the mean from the hdf5 to a numpy file but not sure if that can be used in the prototxt either or converted. I can't find info about this in the Caffe documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, [`"HDF5Data"`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L742-L755) layer does not support transformations. You should subtract the mean values yourself when you store the data to HDF5 files.

If you want to save a numpy array in a binaryproto format, you can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27645934/1714410) for more details.

Comment: Thank's for the answer! Yes that seems to be the case. After writing this question I got this after a while from Caffe: "HDF5Data does not transform data."