# Many challenges to obtain semantic segmentation results for a long time

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe, matcaffe

I did not have any choice except asking here. I have a lot of difficulties for a long time. I have not been to observe any output from FCN32 :(
I trained FCN32 on my data from scratch and always getting a black image. I added `gaussian` with `std= 0.01`  initialization for convolutional layers. But still I get black image.

I [tried to add weighted loss layers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42533280/getting-error-for-adding-infogainloss-layer?noredirect=1#comment72203418_42533280). However, I was not successful to add it correctly. I am not good at python and c++.

My questions:

1. Is there any correct PR that it can easily include this layer?
2. My data has 5 classes that the proportion of classes differ from each other in different images. How can I create these weight matrices for each image?

I really appreciate any help. Please share if you know any resource/link/ or if I can get it from other networks' repositories.

Comment: What do you mean "trained FCN32 on my data from scratch"? Is your network pretrained on another dataset (like ImageNet)?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, No I am training FCN32 from the scratch on my data. I am not using pre-trained model, because my data is medical images and its characteristics is different. Should I use a pretrained model? If yes, could you please let me know which model should I use for the MRI images that I have? could you please let me know what can I do? Thanks a lot again.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro should I fine-tune from a model?

Comment: @S.EB this should be easier

Comment: @Shai Thanks for your message, My data is medical images. Is it ok that I fine tune from other models?If yes, which model can I use? Could you please share the link? I think I should add weighted loss layer as well. It is showing errors. I do not know at which point I am doing wrong.

Comment: @S.EB The FCN papers mention that their networks have to be pretrained on imagenet, or else training just diverges/fails. You will have to find a similar way to do the same. Maybe just pretrain in a classification dataset from your own data.

Comment: You should fine-tune using the fcn-32s-pascal model from https://github.com/shelhamer/fcn.berkeleyvision.org. You should also consider adding "weight_filler: { type: "bilinear" }" to the upscore deconvolution layer in your FCN32 prototxt.